# How to define when auto training should stop?

Tags: machine-learning, google-natural-language, google-cloud-automl-nl

In AutoML Natural Language is there a way I can define parameters/thresholds where training should stop, e.g., after training for 5 hours or when reaching 50% accuracy?

In the documentation there is neither information about how long the model will be trained nor the training/eval progress, so I can't make an informed decision about when I should finish the training.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to define exit criteria for training. AutoML NL will pick the best model fit for users’ problem and optimize the best result. Model training will use all data with valid labels and splits, and respect the split semantic.